# Filtering st_intersect to only consider rows in the data which are the same country in R

Tags: r, geometry, sf, dplyr

I have got a data frame / tibble, which contains the Lat/Long and Country for each data point. Currently, st_intersect is being used to output the row numbers for each row which intersect within the defined ring. The issue with this is that the function does not consider country, but I would like it to only consider rows which are within the ring AND of the same country. So I need to some how incorporate a country consideration when intersecting the points.

DATA

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Country Longitude Latitude
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 France       5.74     45.2
2 France       5.74     45.2
3 Italy        5.74     45.2
```

CODE

```
myDist = 321869

data$UTMnum = ceiling((data$Longitude+180)/6)
data$UTMlet = if_else(data$Latitude>0,"N","S")
data$UTMZone = paste0(data$UTMnum,data$UTMlet)

data = st_as_sf(x = data,coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"),crs = 4326)

myCRS = st_crs(paste0("+proj=utm +zone=",
                          str_replace(str_replace("31N","S",""),"N",""),
                          if_else(grepl("S","31N")," +south",""),
                          " +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"))

dataUTM = st_transform(data,myCRS)

myPoints_buffer = st_buffer(dataUTM,dist = myDist)

myPoints_intersections = st_intersects(dataUTM,dataUTM)

myPoints_intersections = lapply(myPoints_intersections,c)

myPoints_intersections
```

OUTPUT

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

However, I would like this to only show rows where the country is the same.

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1
```